# Need to remove the space element values using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have two types of XML elements, one type is

First XML:

```
<Body>
<h1>aaa</h1>
<h1>bbb</h1>
<h1>ccc</h1>
</Body>
```

Second XML:

```
<Body>
<h1> </h1>
<h1>aaa</h1>
<h1>bbb</h1>
</Body>
```

XSL I'm using as

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="h1"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Body">
      <xsl:copy>
         <h1><xsl:value-of select="h1"/></h1>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="h1"/>
```

Output I'm getting correctly for first XML as like:

```
<Body>
<h1>aaa bbb ccc</h1>
</Body>
```

But even I used strip-space element as h1 for the second xml, I'm getting like below:

```
<Body>
<h1> aaa bbb</h1>
</Body>
```

Expected output be like

```
<Body>
<h1>aaa bbb</h1>
</Body>
```

I Need to remove the space element of h1. But due to that tag, its combining even the space. I used priority and used the seperate h1[normalize-space()] tag also in the template. But its not working. There is having any way to avoid this. Please suggest. I'm using XSLT 2.0 and saxon-PE 9.6.0.7. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Need to remove the space element of h1.

The space that you see is **not** the space in the first `h1` element. It is the separator between the empty string in the first `h1`and the `"aaa"` string in the second `h1` element. You can verify this by doing:

```
<xsl:template match="Body">
      <xsl:copy>
         <h1><xsl:value-of select="h1" separator="-"/></h1>
      </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
```

Demo: http://xsltransform.net/pNmBy1v

To remove the extra space, you could exclude the empty `h1` elements (as suggested by Martin Honnen while I was writing this), or apply `normalize-space()` to the result.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. Its working fine for this tag. I used this tag <h1><xsl:value-of select="h1[normalize-space()]" separator=""/></h1>

Answer (score 1):

I think using `<h1><xsl:value-of select="h1[normalize-space()]"/></h1>` instead of `<h1><xsl:value-of select="h1"/></h1>` should be an easy fix.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Honnen. Its working fine for this tag <h1><xsl:value-of select="h1[normalize-space()]" separator=""/></h1>